# state.data is not iterable NGRX Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to concat the state.data with payload.data but It gives an error:

**TypeError: state.data is not iterable**

My code is:

```
      on(apiActionGroup.success,
        (state, payload) => newState(state,
          { data: { [payload.page?.toString() ?? '0']:  [ ...state.data, ...payload.data]}
        )
  ),
```

If someone knows what is wrong then please let me know. Thanks

Comment: please include your state initialisation code so we can see its type

Answer (score 0):

one of your data objects is undefined or null

```
on(apiActionGroup.success, (state, payload) => {
    const currentData = state.data || [];
    const newData = payload.data || [];
    const key = payload.page?.toString() ?? '0';
    
    return newState(state, {
        data: {
            [key]: [...currentData, ...newData]
        }
    });
}),
```